# How to accept teamviewer license agreement from/under console at first launch

Tags: ssh, console, teamviewer

I have remote Linux machine (ubuntu 14.04) with remote SSH access and fresh installed TeamViewer 10.0.46203 (DEB).

I try to launch teamviewer and obtain TeamViewer ID via ssh console by this command :

```
  $ teamviewer --info
```

which print version, status, id.

But I did not have any success due to the fact that at it **first launch it's required to accept the License agreement**. So I try to launch with `-X` key via SSH but this window with accept the License agreement button does not appear! Only when it fail to accept license appear window with error message.

My question: how to accept teamviewer license agreement from/under console at first launch?

Answer (score 6):

I wrote same question to teamviewer support and got such reply:

> When installing TeamViewer through SSH please keep in mind there is an EULA agreement which must be accepted before the GUI is able to launch to receive an ID.
>
> There will be a parameter for this coming out in a later release, however, for now please stop the TeamViewer daemon with the following command:
>
> `teamviewer --daemon stop`
>
> and then just add the following lines in the /opt/teamviewer9/config/global.config file:
>
> `[int32] EulaAccepted = 1`
>
> `[int32] EulaAcceptedRevision = 6`
>
> After this please start the TeamViewer daemon with the following command:
>
> `teamviewer --daemon start`
>
> Also, please run the command (in debian based distros)
>
> `export DISPLAY=:0; nohup iceweasel &>/dev/null &`
>
> to allow the GUI to be opened and retrieve the TeamViewer ID.
>
> You can then run TeamViewer with the command `sudo teamviewer & disown` as it removes the process from the shell's job control, but it still leaves it connected to the terminal.
>
> Thank you in advance and please let me know if you have any further questions...
>
> Fedora 20
>   Here are the steps:
>
> 1.) SSH into the machine to install TeamViewer (Follow installation instructions. If help is needed for shell commands then `teamviewer --help`)
>   2.) After installing TeamViewer please setup the unattended password `teamviewer --passwd [PASSWD]`
>   3.) After please stop the daemon with `sudo teamviewer --daemon stop`
>   4.) Write into the global.conf file located in /opt/teamviewer/config/global.conf the following lines:
>
> `[int32] Always_Online = 1`
>
> `[int32] EulaAccepted = 1`
>
> `[int32] EulaAcceptedRevision = 6`
>
> 5.) Then start the daemon with `sudo teamviewer --daemon --start` or restart if needed `sudo teamviewer --daemon restart`
>
> 6.) Then restart GDM with the command `systemctl restart gdm.service`
>
> Then you should be good to go!

Answer (score 5):

In TeamViewer 10 there is a option `licence`, with which you can accept the EULA.

```
$teamviewer license accept
```

You may need to restart teamviewer daemon with `$teamviewer daemon restart`.

Comment: Just tried, I can confirm that it works for TeamViewer 13 as well.

Answer (score -1):

## teamviewer license accept

Device is not assigned to an account. Please run interactive setup.